# Meteor how to perform database migrations?

Tags: database, upgrade, migrate, meteor, downgrade

How do you perform database migrations with Meteor?  With Ruby on Rails there is ActiveRecord::Migration.  Is there an equivalent mechanism in Meteor?

For example, I make an app with some user data.  I'm storing the data in Mongo using a JSON format.  The app changes, and the JSON database schema needs to change.  I can write a migration method to change the schema, however, I only want this to run if the server database is out of date.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's nothing built in for this.  What I've done myself for now is similar to how Rails works, but as part of startup instead of a separate task.  First create a `Meteor.Collection` called Migrations, and then for each discrete migration, create a function under the `server` subdirectory that runs on startup.  It should only run the migration if it hasn't run before, and it should flag the migration in the Migrations collection once its done.

```
// database migrations
Migrations = new Meteor.Collection('migrations');

Meteor.startup(function () {
  if (!Migrations.findOne({name: "addFullName"})) {
    Users.find().forEach(function (user) {
      Users.update(user._id, {$set: {fullname: users.firstname + ' ' + users.lastname}});
    });
    Migrations.insert({name: "addFullName"});
  }
});
```

You could extend this technique to support down migrations (look for the existence of a given migration and reverse it), enforce a sort order on the migrations, and split each migration into a separate file if you wanted.

It'd be interesting to think about a smart package for automating this.

Comment: I might eventually get the motivation to make a smart package with this logic. This is still better than an obscure Meteor method.

Comment: If you have more than one server running on the same database (multiple web servers or micro-services), you may run into trouble when 5 servers all run the same query.  This package appears to use a [locking mechanism](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations/blob/master/migrations_server.js#L159)

Answer (score 6):

As Aram pointed already in the comment, p[ercolate:migrations](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations) package gives you what you need. Sample

```
Migrations.add({
    version: 1,
    name: 'Adds pants to some people in the db.',
    up: function() {//code to migrate up to version 1}
    down: function() {//code to migrate down to version 0}
});

Migrations.add({
    version: 2,
    name: 'Adds a hat to all people in the db who are wearing pants.',
    up: function() {//code to migrate up to version 2}
    down: function() {//code to migrate down to version 1}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I created a smart package for this use case.
See https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/migrations

Comment: There's also https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations which seems to me to have a cleaner design than https://github.com/rantav/meteor-migrations.